# If $ n^2+2 $ and $ n^2-2 $ are prime numbers, then $n$ is divisible by $3$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $n>1$ ($n \in \Bbb N$) and,if $ n^2+2 $ and $ n^2-2 $ are prime numbers, prove that $n$ is divisible by $3$.

I have been trying to solve this with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 3 must divide exactly one of $\{a-2,a,a+2\}$ for any integer $a$. [In fact 3 must divide exactly one of $\{a-1,a,a+1\}$. Furthermore 3 must divide exactly one of $\{a-k,a,a+k\}$ for any integer $a$ and any integer $k$ relatively prime to 3.]

So setting $a=n^2$, it follows that 3 must divide exactly one of $\{n^2-2,n^2,n^2+2\}$.

But $n^2-2$ and $n^2+2$ are prime, so which of $\{n^2-2,n^2,n^2+2\}$ does 3 divide again? And then after that...

> And if 3 divides $n^2$, then does 3 also divide $n$?

Answer (score 3):

Product of three consecutive numbers is divisible by $3$. Consider $n^2,n^2+1,n^2+2$ and $n^2-2,n^2-1,n^2$. Assume $3$ does not divide $n$. So $3$ does not divide $n^2$. Then $3$ divides $n^2+1$ and $n^2-1$. Can you complete now ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to express this using modular arithmetic...

If $n$ is not divisible by 3 then either $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. In the first case, $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and so $n^2 + 2 \equiv 3 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ and so $n^2 + 2$ is composite. In the second case, $n^2 \equiv 4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and we have the same implication as before.

In either case, $n^2 + 2$ is composite. So actually all we needed was that $n^2 + 2$ is prime, and then $n$ is divisible by 3.

In fact, $3 \nmid n^2 + 2 \iff 3 \mid n$.

$$n \equiv 0 \equiv n^2 \pmod 3$$
$$\iff n^2 + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$$

This works since 3 is prime, so $3 \mid n^2 \implies 3 \mid n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if not, $n^2+2$ is divisible by ...

Comment: You mean "either $n^2+2$ or $n^2-2$ is divisible by...", right?

Comment: Which is what I did though......my question was directed at @Robert Israel...I think that is what he meant to write but of course I am not positive

Comment: @Mike I think he does not mean "either". If n = 1 (mod 3) or n = 2 (mod 3) then $n^2 +2$ is divisible by 3.

Comment: @Omer yes indeed, in light of your comment I do see it now. Thanks!